# mysql e php - subtrair dois últimos registros de uma mesma coluna e dividir pelo ultimo registro de outra coluna

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho uma tabela `carro_log` que guarda o histórico de updates de outra tabela.

```
id  kilometragem  combustivel  dt_atualização
 1      200           45         2017-05-03
 2      400           35         2017-05-03
 1      150           38         2017-05-02
 3      220           30         2017-05-01
 .       .             .             .  
 .       .             .             .
```

O cálculo do rendimento dos carros é **(kilometragem atual - kilometragem anterior) / combustivel atual** de cada id (carro). Como posso fazer isso? Selecionar e subtrair o valor atual e anterior de uma mesma coluna?

Comment: Para um determinado id (carro), o último registro é o atual e, o anterior é o imediatamente com data menor?

Comment: Para a mesma id, sim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A consulta abaixo irá retornar em uma nova coluna o rendimento (conforme sua fórmula):

```
select *,
       cast((select (car.kilometragem - cAnt.kilometragem) * 1.0
             from carro_log cAnt
             where cAnt.id = car.id 
                   and cAnt.dt_atualizacao < car.dt_atualizacao
             order by dt_atualizacao desc
             limit 1)
            / car.combustivel as decimal(7,2))  as 'Rendimento'
from carro_log car
order by dt_atualizacao
```

Para a mesma tabela fiz dois *selects*:
- car = ATUAL
- cAnt = O REGISTRO ANTERIOR

Na subconsulta é feita a subtração pelo registro imediatamente anterior (utilizando o `limit 1` para garantir apenas um (1)) e também fiz uma multiplicação por 1.0 - para converter para `float` (poderia ser com `cast` normalmente).
Por último, é feita a divisão pelo combustível atual e a conversão para `decimal(7,2)` - para somente com duas casas decimais.

Comment: Olá Ismael, grato pela resposta. Quase isso. Fiz um teste, mas ele mantem o primeiro valor sempre como anterior para a subtração. Ou seja, se eu registro o carro e  faço os dois primeiros updates de kilometragem o resultado da certinho. Mas se eu fizer o terceiro ele pega o mais atual e subtrai com o primeiro e não do imediatamente anterior (segundo registro).

Comment: Faltou um order by desc... Vou corrigir

Comment: Grande Ismael...perfeito..funcionou 100%. Abraços.